# How to get a deep link from firebase dynamic link in React Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using firebase dynamic links in my React Native app but I am unable to get deep link from the dynamic link. I have searched on internet regarding this but didn't found anything. If someone had worked on this before than please help me.

Comment: First you should ensure you configure your native projects. You can see the oficial documentation https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage